# Error installing Python 2 via Homebrew on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: homebrew, python-2.x, macos-high-sierra

I experience troubles installing Python@2 via homebrew on MacOS High Sierra. During the make process it simply fails with the "expected function body after function declarator error" on several occasions.

Based on the messages from the make process it seems that it has to do something with the fact Command Line Tools on High Sierra are updated to MacOSX10.14.sdk. The question now is how to downgrade the SDK to 10.13?

```
clang -c -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Modules/main.o Modules/main.c
clang -c -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Modules/gcmodule.o Modules/gcmodule.c
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/threadmodule.c -o Modules/threadmodule.o
In file included from Python/mactoolboxglue.c:27:
In file included from Include/pymactoolbox.h:10:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:20:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:24:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/AE.framework/Headers/AE.h:29:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/AE.framework/Headers/AppleEvents.h:597:165: error: expected function body after function declarator
extern OSStatus AEDeterminePermissionToAutomateTarget( const AEAddressDesc* target, AEEventClass theAEEventClass, AEEventID theAEEventID, Boolean askUserIfNeeded ) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING( __MAC_10_14, __IPHONE_NA );
                                                                                                                                                                    ^
/usr/include/Availability.h:216:50: note: expanded from macro '__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING'
    #define __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(_osx, _ios) __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL##_osx
                                                 ^
<scratch space>:95:1: note: expanded from here
__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__MAC_10_14
^
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/signalmodule.c -o Modules/signalmodule.o
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/posixmodule.c -o Modules/posixmodule.o
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/errnomodule.c -o Modules/errnomodule.o
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/pwdmodule.c -o Modules/pwdmodule.o
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/_sre.c -o Modules/_sre.o
In file included from Python/mactoolboxglue.c:27:
In file included from clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/_codecsmodule.c -o Modules/_codecsmodule.o
Include/pymactoolbox.h:10:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:67:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:200:51: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef struct OpaqueInkTextRef*        InkTextRef DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14_AND_LATER;
                                                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:222:53: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef struct OpaqueInkStrokeRef*      InkStrokeRef DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14_AND_LATER;
                                                    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:251:49: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef struct InkPoint                 InkPoint DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14_AND_LATER;
                                                ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:252:52: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef InkPoint *                      InkPointPtr DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14_AND_LATER;
                                                   ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:262:58: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef CFIndex                         InkAlternateCount DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14_AND_LATER;
                                                         ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:274:63: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef FourCharCode                    InkUserWritingModeType DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14_AND_LATER;
                                                              ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:289:70: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef FourCharCode                    InkApplicationWritingModeType DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14_AND_LATER;
                                                                     ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:303:34: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef UInt32 InkDrawingModeType DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14_AND_LATER;
                                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:318:36: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef UInt32 InkTextDrawFlagsType DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14_AND_LATER;
                                   ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:361:34: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef UInt32 InkTerminationType DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14_AND_LATER;
                                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:427:29: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef UInt32 InkSourceType DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14_AND_LATER;
                            ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:454:34: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef UInt32 InkRecognitionType DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14_AND_LATER;
                                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:546:36: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef FourCharCode InkGestureKind DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14_AND_LATER;
                                   ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:776:63: error: expected function body after function declarator
InkUserWritingMode(void)                                      AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_3_AND_LATER_BUT_DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14;
                                                              ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:810:73: error: expected function body after function declarator
InkSetApplicationWritingMode(InkApplicationWritingModeType iWriteWhere) AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_3_AND_LATER_BUT_DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14;
                                                                        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:837:71: error: expected function body after function declarator
InkSetApplicationRecognitionMode(InkRecognitionType iRecognitionType) AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_3_AND_LATER_BUT_DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14;
                                                                      ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:901:63: error: expected function body after function declarator
  InkTerminationType   iAllowedTerminationTypes)              AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_3_AND_LATER_BUT_DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14;
                                                              ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Headers/Ink.h:934:63: error: expected function body after function declarator
InkIsPhraseInProgress(void)                                   AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_3_AND_LATER_BUT_DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_14;
                                                              ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -c ./Modules/_weakref.c -o Modules/_weakref.o
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Python/mactoolboxglue.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I know that Python is installed in the MacOS but this is dependency for two tools I wanted to install through Homebrew.

Comment: I was able to resolve this using:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31679#issuecomment-423259873

Comment: Sure, I found this one but the comment afterwards tell you that this is no longer valid solution since Apple has pushed the new XCode and Command Line Tools. However, I see in the comment from yesterday that it is possible to select different version of XCode with xcode-select --install. I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @DarkCastle. Thank you. Once I removed Command Line Tools by simply deleting it I could install xcode and it created a soft link for both versions MacOSX10.13.sdk and MacOSX.14.sdk which point to MacOSX.sdk. I guess I can now write a complete answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve the problem the Command Line Tools should be reinstalled in two steps:

1. Remove the Command Line Tools

> sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

2. Installing Command Line Tools

> xcode-select --install

The newly installed version creates a symlink for both versions, MacOSX10.13.sdk and MacOSX.14.sdk.